# Python 'object() takes no parameters' error

Tags: python, class, object

I have the class parameter below which should return the index of 2 numbers within the 'nums' list that sums up to the target.

When I tried to test the class using 9 as the target by writing 'Solution(nums,9)', Python returned the 'TypeError: object() takes no parameters' error. Can anyone advise me on what I did wrong in my script?

```
nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        nums_1 = nums        
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for a in range(len(nums_1)):
                if i != a:
                    if nums[i] + nums_1[a] == target:
                        return(sorted([i, a]))
Solution(nums,9)

Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: function seems more appropriate for your cases than class

Comment: @CommentInHashes: That'll have a different error, because without an instance of `Solution`, it will complain about receiving two arguments when it expects three (the third being `self`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thats True. I'll make the edit, I forgot the braces.

Comment: Do `Solution().twoSum(nums, 9)`, also there are a lot of logical optimizations in the code that you can do to make sure it run in O(n) instead of O(n**2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use it like that, because your class have default __init__(which your class get by default, since you didn't define it), and it doesn't take any parameters unless you define it to take it.

Use the following:

```
sol = Solution()
sorted_stuff = sol.twoSum(nums, 9)
print(sorted_stuff)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the `__init__()` method while defining your *Solution* class. Its not always compulsory, but since you are creating an instance of the class by calling `Solution()` with some arguments, the `__init__` method must be implemented. So the implementation can be:

```
_nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
class Solution(object):
    def __init(nums, target):
      self.nums = nums
      self.target = target

    def twoSum(self, nums=None, target=None):
        if not nums:
           nums = self.nums

        if not target:
           target= self.target

        nums_1 = nums        
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for a in range(len(nums_1)):
                if i != a:
                    if nums[i] + nums_1[a] == target:
                        return(sorted([i, a]))
s = Solution(_nums,9)
s.twoSum()
```

Also you can do:

```
 s = Solution()
 s.twoSum(_nums,9)
```

This gives you the freedom to either have the args defined during the class initialization or calling the actual method with the args.